# Где разница в компиляции между gcc (Debian) и MS VS 2017 (Win10)

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int a = 2;

    a = a++ + ++a;
    
    printf("%d", a);
}
```

В линуксе: 6

В win10 (компилятор MS Visual Studio Community 2017): 7

Как получается "7" - не могу найти объяснения

Comment: ¿А какой результат тут ожидается и почему?

Comment: Потому что тут надо использовать либо скобки, либо не писать такие выражения.

Comment: Это выражение приводит к [неопределённому поведению](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B). Это значит что результат может быть любым на любом компиляторе, даже отличаться при различных запусках одной и той же программы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разные результаты от разного порядка вычисления аргументов. Стандарт не оговаривает, какой аргумент нужно вычислять первым. И разные компиляторы это делают по-своему.
Чтобы понять надо посмотреть пошагово. Вот как вычисляет gcc :

```
a++ => 2  // a == 2 (пост - инкремент)
++a => 3  // a == 3 (пре - инкремент)
a = 2 + 3 // a == 5
// после окончания вычислений происходит пост - инкремент a++
a = a + 1 // a == 6
```

а вот MS наоборот :

```
++a => 3  // a == 3 (пре - инкремент)
a++ => 3  // a == 3 (пост - инкремент)
a = 3 + 3 // a == 6
// после окончания вычислений происходит пост - инкремент a++
a = a + 1 // a == 7
```

Comment: т.е. VS начинает суммирование с правого аргумента, получается?

Comment: если рассматривать ваш пример для gсс, то b дожно быть равно 5, а оно 6
`void main() { int a = 2; int b = 0; b = a++ + ++a; printf("%d %d", a, b); }`

Comment: у "b" нет пост-инкремента

Comment: посмотрел https://godbolt.org/z/qbv6osceE , теперь `gcc` для удобства сначала работает с правым аргументом и прибавляет единицу. Никто не запрещает.

Comment: gcc работает по-стандарту, он не обязан ловить программиста на его изменение левого аргумента , при вычислении правого. Дальше уже всё будет на совести программиста с его неопределённым поведением проги.

Comment: спасибо за инструмент: https://godbolt.org/

Comment: Как оказалось, (https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order): "Порядок вычисления любой части любого выражения, включая порядок вычисления аргументов функции, является неопределённым .. В C++ нет понятия вычисления слева направо или справа налево"

Comment: Рассуждать о работе программы с неопределённым поведением - тратить время зря.

Answer (score 2):

Выражение `a = a++ + ++a;` приводит к [неопределённому поведению](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B). Это значит что **результат может быть любым** на любом компиляторе, даже отличаться при различных запусках одной и той же программы.

Рассуждать о работе программы с неопределённым поведением - тратить время зря.

Правильно настроенный компилятор отказывается обрабатывать такой код:

```
// gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror temp.c

int main() {
    int a = 2;
    a = a++ + ++a;
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror temp.c 
> temp.c: In function ‘main’:
> temp.c:5:7: error: operation on ‘a’ may be undefined [-Werror=sequence-point]
>     5 |     a = a++ + ++a;
>       |     ~~^~~~~~~~~~~
> temp.c:5:7: error: operation on ‘a’ may be undefined [-Werror=sequence-point]
> cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
> ```